# Images.xcassets: [UIImage imageNamed:@"group/image"]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uiimage

Assuming you have the following *.xcassets configuration:

[image]

Two (or multiple) groups containing same-named files.

-> How to refer to images within a certain group by using `[UIImage imageNamed:]` or any other UIImage constructor?
Just like: `[UIImage imageNamed:@"group/myImage"]`
Any ideas?

PS: Renaming the files and give each a **unique** filename is of course possible. But I find it more structured to have them grouped.

Comment: possible duplicate of [xcode 4: how to load images from a specific group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522833/xcode-4-how-to-load-images-from-a-specific-group)

Comment: not sure - xcasset is different from former xcode4 image management.

Comment: Pretty sure it works the same way though - since groups are just a logical organizer within Xcode.

Comment: well, but creating actual folders is not possible using xcassets. Xcode is automatically managing the files and grouping them in imagesets. I'm not sure if you can refer to them in imageNamed. (like "folder/124.imageset/myImage")